# conditional calculation: length of certain row when row below is not NA value

Tags: r, row, na

I have the following df:

```
           X7 X8   X9 X10 X11  X12  X13  X14  
1          1  1 <NA>   1   1    1    1  <NA>    
2          1  1    1   1   1    1  <NA> <NA> 
3          1  1    1   1   1  <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

**Edit:** Using this:

```
df <- data.frame(X7=c(1L,1L,1L),X8=c(1L,1L,1L),X9=factor(c(NA,'1','1')),X10=c(1L,1L,1L),X11=c(1L,1L,1L),X12=factor(c('1','1',NA)),X13=factor(c('1',NA,NA)),X14=factor(c(NA,NA,NA)));
```

I want to calculate the length of row `1` excluding NA's when the values in row `2` are not NA values. And then do the same for row `1` and `3`.

So the result for rows `1-2` should be 5 and rows `1-3` should be 4.

I have no idea how to go about this apart from knowing how to calculate the length of each row:

```
(apply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) length(x[!is.na(x)])))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't the result for rows 1 and 2 be 5?

Comment: `"NA"` is not the same as `NA`.  Your code creates a character matrix, not a data frame.

Comment: @RichardScriven is correct. For my answer, I created my own definition of `df` which reproduces the print output shown in the question. The `cbind()` call shown in the question is likely the source of the inconsistency and should be ignored.

Comment: @bgoldst - You are correct - apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would precompute a logical matrix representing which cells are *not* NA, and then iterate over all row indexes beyond the first with an `sapply()` call. Within the lambda you can do a logical AND between the current row and the first row to get common non-NAs and then use `sum()` to count how many there are.

```
df <- data.frame(X7=c(1L,1L,1L),X8=c(1L,1L,1L),X9=factor(c(NA,'1','1')),X10=c(1L,1L,1L),X11=c(1L,1L,1L),X12=factor(c('1','1',NA)),X13=factor(c('1',NA,NA)),X14=factor(c(NA,NA,NA)));
nons <- !is.na(df);
sapply(seq(2L,len=nrow(df)-1L),function(ri) sum(nons[1L,]&nons[ri,]));
## [1] 5 4
```

---

Alternatively, you can precompute the column indexes in the first row that have non-NA, and then from inside the lambda call `intersect()` against the indexes in the current row that have non-NA.

```
nons <- !is.na(df);
nons1 <- unname(which(nons[1L,]));
sapply(seq(2L,len=nrow(df)-1L),function(ri) length(intersect(nons1,which(nons[ri,]))));
## [1] 5 4
```

Comment: Another way would be `m <- t(!is.na(df)); colSums(m[,1] & m)[-1]`

Comment: Crap, well done @MaratTalipov! I briefly cogitated on the possibility of achieving a completely vectorized solution, but for some reason decided it wasn't possible, so settled for `sapply()`. You should post an answer; I'd upvote it.

Comment: @MaratTalipov so to be able to calculate between row `2` -`3` within the same code I'm assuming I'd have to loop it?. Thank you very much guys!

Comment: I think you can avoid looping by using matrix multiplication, `result <- crossprod(m,m)`. The answer for 2-3 will be `result[2,3]`